# How can deregister scripts for a certain custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I use the functions.php to register and enqueue all of the scripts and css for my website.

I have one custom post type that i want to pick and choose which scripts get loaded into the single-post-type.php page.  I open this page in a lightbox so I don't want to load all of the javascript and css files into the page.  It could get rather cumbersome.  I'm trying to

Is this possible and how might i go about doing this?

I tried wrapping a few of the scripts with this code and it didnt seem to do anything:

```
if ( is_singular( 'projects' ) ) {
  wp_deregister_script('html5shiv');
}
```

I go to my template and still see html5shiv being loaded.  What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion, if you are the one registering and enqueing the scripts and styles, enqueue them conditionally. I don't see any use enqueueing a scripts or styles just to dequeue them later on.

If you want to take the dequeue route, you need to

- dequeue the script or style, not deregister it
- Make sure your priority is correct, ie, you must dequeue the script or style **after** it is properly loaded. Doing this **before** the script or style is properly loaded wont work

### EXAMPLE 1

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );
function enqueue_my_scripts()
{
    wp_register_script( 'my_script', /* Add the rest of your details*/ );
    if ( !is_singular( 'my_post_type' ) ) // If we are not on a single post page from my my_post_type, enqueue the script
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script' );
}
```

### EXAMPLE 2

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_my_scripts', 999 ); // Notice the priority
function dequeue_my_scripts()
{
    if ( is_singular( 'my_post_type' ) ) // If we are on a single post page from my my_post_type, dequeue the script
        wp_dequeue_script( 'my_script' );
}
```

Comment: yeah, thats the ticket...Thank you.  I think that will work great.